# Problem with interruption of ajax request in RichFaces

Tags: jsf, seam, richfaces

I use seam and RichFaces in the project. If user performs action to leave the page (i.e. clicks s:link) while a4j ajax request is still active then alert with error 599 appears (Request error, status : 599 Network error).

I can found error logs only in `<a4j:log>` output:

> debug[17:56:32,419]: NEW AJAX REQUEST !!! with form: aforma
>   debug[17:56:32,420]: Start XmlHttpRequest
>   debug[17:56:32,421]: Request state : 1
>   debug[17:56:32,428]: QueryString:   AJAXREQUEST=_viewRoot&aforma%3Aj_id62%3Aname=&aforma%3Aj_id74%3Aj_id82=&aforma%3AproductFileUploadLink%3Afile=&aforma%3Aj_id125=20&aforma%3AconfirmationPanelOpenedState=&aforma%3Aj_id177=confirm1&aforma=aforma&autoScroll=&javax.faces.ViewState=j_id4&aforma%3Aj_id86%3AcontentType=0&ajaxSingle=aforma%3Aj_id86%3AcontentType&aforma%3Aj_id86%3Aj_id95=aforma%3Aj_id86%3Aj_id95&
>   debug[17:56:40,338]: Request state : 4
>   debug[17:56:40,338]: Request end with state 4
>   **error[17:56:40,338]: Request error, status : 0**
>   **debug[17:56:43,551]: No parsed XML document in response**
>   debug[17:56:43,551]: Processing updates finished, no oncomplete function to call

What is the better way to avoid such errors?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... In JSF2 you can add your own errorHandler. In Javascript:

```
var handleError = function(data) {
  //handle error here
};
jsf.ajax.addOnError(handleError);
```

Probably there is something similar in RichFaces.